# Unable to Create partition to install ubuntu

Tags: installation, partitioning

Unable to install Ubuntu in the 'UNUSABLE' space to create partition for Ubuntu, how can i install Ubuntu.[image]

Comment: Post the screenshot of your disk partition.

Comment: How old is this hard drive?

Comment: There are four primary partition, which is the limit, you have to delete one of them to create new ones.

Comment: what error you are getting? I think Ubuntu installs easily on extended patitions also.

Answer (score 1):

I don't know for sure (it's been awhile), but I think you have created the maximum number of primary partitions.  You can have a maximum of four primary partitions, and you appear to be at that number.  In order to create more partitions, you'll need to delete one of those partitions (probably sda4), and then create a new extended partition, which you can divide into logical partitions.